# SQL join result fulltext

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, which I will call table1 and table2. Table1 has 2 fields, id and auth, table2 also has two fields, id and keywords. Note that id of table1 and table2 match.
This is my query:

```
SELECT id, MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('example') FROM table2 WHERE MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('example')
```

How am I going to exclude results where the auth (table1) of that same id is not 1?

Comment: Could you tell us what RDBS you're using - MySQL, MS SQL, Oracle ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('example') 
  FROM table2 t2
 WHERE MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('example')
   AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.id and t1.auth != 1)
```

Comment: Hey Pete, what is the purpose of the `Select 1 From table1 ....` in the last line?

Comment: Hi @Evan, the questioner wanted to exclude matching rows where table1.auth did not equal 1. The subquery gets all the matching rows from table1 where the auth field was not 1 ... and the the `NOT EXISTS` clause excludes them. The `select 1` part is just a convention I use; you could substitute almost anything in its place:  `select *` or `select 'x'` would both work.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.id != t2.id
```